# The problem in understanding how to distribute the empty space between the items of a flex box that has the same feature of flex grow

Tags: flexbox

```
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: rgb(204, 128, 128); flex-basis:0%; flex-shrink:0;">1</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: rgb(22, 84, 218); flex-basis: 0%;   flex-shrink: 0; ">254556</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: rgb(77, 228, 17); flex-basis:0%;   flex-shrink: 0; ">3</div>

</div>  In the code above, if there is no empty space in the flex container, the middle div item is larger because it has a larger content, but if there is empty space, it is divided between the first and third items until both of them are equal the middle item, but I thought that if the flex grow of all three items is equal to 1, all three items should grow at the same rate, so why doesn't the middle item grow with it until the other two items are the same size?
```

The second div will not grow until the size of the two elements next to it are equal to it. I need the exact formula to calculate the growth rate of each item in such cases.